# PHP Array element returning null when accessed directly

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, var-dump

Any idea why this would happen?

code:

```
<?php
print_r($this->$property);
var_dump($this->$property[0]);
?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 34901
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2013-01-04 21:04:34
            [post_date_gmt] => 2013-01-05 02:04:34
            [post_content] => 
            [post_title] => Castro Theater  
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => open
            [ping_status] => open
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => castro-theater
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2013-01-04 21:04:34
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2013-01-05 02:04:34
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://demo.gala.local/2012/venues/castro-theater/
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => venue
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
            [p2p_id] => 34444
            [p2p_from] => 34891
            [p2p_to] => 34901
            [p2p_type] => scheduleitem_to_venue
        )

)
NULL
```

Comment: If you are accessing a class property, you shoudl `$this -> property[0]`

Comment: Please do not use foul words to avoid being flagged.

Comment: @Starx $property is a variable that contains the name of the property, not the property itself.

Comment: Can you access the property directly without the variable?

Comment: @Starx If you will notice from my example, I can access it using the variable, just not one of the elements inside.

Comment: Then just use `{}` like `$this -> {$property}[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code ends up processesing `$property[0]` first, then tries to fetch the property of your object with the result of that.  If you get `$this->$property` first, then you can fetch things using the normal array notation and things will work as you expect.

```
$data = $this->$property;
var_dump($data[0]);
```

Comment: Ah, I get it. Thanks! I have fixed it by using `$this->{$property}[0]`